# Как добавить значение в объект списка?

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter

Имеется ArrayList

Для него написал адаптер, в нем пытаюсь написать метод, который бы вставлял значение в объект.

```
public class PredanceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Playlist> playlist;

PredanceAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Playlist> playlist){
    this.context = context;
    this.playlist = playlist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return playlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return playlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void addItem(String string,int position){
    Playlist playlist = (Playlist) getItem(position);
    playlist.setVALUE(string);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.predancelist_layout,null);
    }
    Playlist playlists = (Playlist)getItem(position);

    TextView forid = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.forid);
    TextView forname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.forname);
    TextView forvalue = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.forvalue);

    forid.setText(playlists.getPLAYNUM());
    forname.setText(playlists.getM_NAME()+"/"+playlists.getW_NAME());
    forvalue.setText(playlists.getVALUE());

    return convertView;
}}
```

Прошу помочь с реализацией метода addItem :P

Comment: Добавьте код класса `Playlist`.

Comment: @post_zeew в playlist мы добавляем значение string (setVALUE)

Comment: `playlist.get(position).setVALUE(string); notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что Вы хотите сделать: изменить определенный элемент или вставить новый элемент в список в определенную позицию?

Comment: Все заработало, проблема оказалась в другом))) Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: вы бы добавили проверку на null -  а то так напрашивается в конструкторе именно его передать и словить NullPointerException при обращении к методам...